# file_get_contents not outputting svg

Tags: php, wordpress, svg

I'm trying to grab an svg file with php and output it onto a page. Site is built on Wordpress.

```
<?php 
    echo file_get_contents("site.com/wp-content/themes/oaklandcentral/img/fb_logo.svg"); 
?>
```

Nothing is displaying. The actual link is correct and goes directly to the svg. Any thoughts?

Comment: Have you viewed the page source to see what you are getting?

Comment: Try readfile - http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php

Comment: Page source returning nothing, same issues with the readfile function.

Answer (score 4):

Path is wrong, use `file_get_contents( get_template_directory() . '/img/fb_logo.svg' )`

Comment: Url in the question is accurate! Unfortunately this isn't retuning anything to the DOM either.

Comment: Thanks, this is related to WordPress =)

Answer (score 4):

`echo file_get_contents("site.com/wp-content/themes/oaklandcentral/img/fb_logo.svg");`

Assumptions:

- your "filename" string starts with the protocol e.g. "http://"

  that you can access the file directly from a browser (i.e. not a
  file/folder permissions issue);

  that file_get_contents is returning FALSE? (does the E_WARNING tell
  you anything?)

I recollect seeing that **some servers are not configured to allow file_get_contents** (or readfile with URLs) so I would check investigate this first (maybe **[allow_url_fopen](http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen)** in php.ini???).

If this is not the case (or is a limitation by host provider) and you cannot find the cause of the problem then CURL *should* work (on most servers!).

```
$url = 'http://example.com/path-to/fb_logo.svg';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$svg = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

echo $svg;
```

**Edit:**

1. It also appears you could also use php `include` [if you remove the xml header tag from your SVG file](https://sheelahb.com/blog/how-to-get-php-to-play-nicely-with-svg-files/).
2. I assume you want to display the SVG image not its text code, in which case why not simply `<img src="<?php echo $mySvgFileUrl"; ?>">` like any other image?

Answer (score 1):

Add header using: `header("Content-Type: image/svg+xml");` before you echo the svg. sometimes the browser assumes the data received is html by default.

Comment: No luck, still returning nothing to the dom.

Answer (score 0):

What could possibly be the problem.

1. The file isn't where you think it is.
2. File permission isn't allowing the code to read the file.

Try to debug:

```
<?php 
    $file = "site.com/wp-content/themes/oaklandcentral/img/fb_logo.svg";
    if ( file_exists($file) ) {
        echo file_get_contents($file); 
    } else {
        echo "File $file does not exist";
    }
?>
```

Try to get the page with curl. Take a look at the headers and the raw https response.

```
curl -v URL_TO_PAGE
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

`<?php echo file_get_contents(get_template_directory().'/theme/img/chevron-right-solid.svg'); ?>`

this seemed to work for me, where using `get_template_directory_uri()` did not (it threw an OpenSSL error)

Then, you can target the SVG and style how you wish.
For example:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary">
  <?php echo file_get_contents(get_template_directory().'/theme/img/chevron-right-solid.svg'); ?>
</button>
```

CSS might be:

`.btn svg { line-height: 1.2; max-height: 1rem;}`

Answer (score 0):

This PHP Code should work:

```
$svgfilename = 'fb_logo.svg';
$svgcontent = false;        
$svgcontent = file_get_contents(get_template_directory() . '/wp-content/themes/oaklandcentral/img/' . $svgfilename));
//We can str_replace some values here such as width="32", height="32", viewBox="0 0 32 32", etc.
print '<a title="'.trim(basename($svgfilename)).'" href="'.get_template_directory() . '/wp-content/themes/oaklandcentral/img/' . $svgfilename.'" >'.$svgcontent.'</a>';
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to use below code.

$opts = array(
  'http'=>array(
    'method'=>"GET",
    'header'=>"Accept-language: en\r\n" .
              "Cookie: foo=bar\r\n"
  )
);

$context = stream_context_create($opts);

$file = file_get_contents('site.com/wp-content/themes/oaklandcentral/img/fb_logo.svg', false, $context);